# How can I start an animation when a ViewModel property changes?

Tags: silverlight, animation, mvvm, windows-phone-7

I have a view model that has a "IsSearchVisible" property. When it gets set to true I want it to start an animation in the view that slides down the search box. Anyway to achieve this in Silverlight/WP7?

Answer (score 1):

Here's [one approach](http://www.thejoyofcode.com/Model_View_ViewModel_and_Animation.aspx).

Comment: I found REALLY interesting this link. Don't know why it's not the accepted answer.